# Screen gets cut and hangs for few seconds upon rotation

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

My windows 8 store xaml app gets cut in half upon rotation from landscape mode to Portrait mode and vice versa. Upon rotation the screen gets hanged for a second and gets cut. After a pause of around 3 seconds it gets adjusted to portrait mode. To get the app adjust in portrait mode i have written a storyboard that resizes the buttons and other columns.Then we are calling this storyboard or viewstate on size changed event. We have noticed that many Microsoft apps like mail, people, news apps has the same behaviour. Is there any way to fix this? Or does all the apps on Surface take time to re-adjust? Any reason for this? How can I fix it? Please check the screen shot taken at the time of rotation..
[image]

Comment: Did you try using VisualStateManager from within your XAML?

Comment: Yes, VisualStateManager is written in XAML and is called whenever the size changed event is triggered